# Cannot get String Length due to its type in C++/CLI

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, clr

I am trying to build a C++/CLR form app
And in the code below
I am trying to get the length of the string of `GetTb`
Which is a string retrieved from a textbox `Tb_Return`

```
Tb_Return->Text = "This is a test String";
String^ GetTb = Tb_Return->Text;
int len = GetTb.Length();
Tb_Return->Text = GetTb;
```

In Line 3, Visual Studio keeps highlighting the `GetTb` variable with the error below

> expression must have class type but it has type

And when I try to change the `.` into `->`, the error message changes to below

> expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have have (pointer-to-) function type

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error into your question.

Comment: I replaced the c++ tag with c++/cli as these are 2 different languages and the question is related to the later only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are **2 issues** here:

1. `GetTb` is a [handle to an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=msvc-170) in c++/cli.
   In order to dereference it you must use the **`->` operator** (or `*` with `.` similarly to c++ pointers).
2. [`System::String::Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=net-7.0) is a **property**.
   In order to access it you need to use its name **without** parentheses (`()`).

Therefore the **correct way** to access the `Length` property of `GetTb` is:

```
int len = GetTb->Length;
```

Comment: After I changed the code, the program is running fine  
However when do "Tb_Return->Text = to_String(GetTb);"  
The "Tb_Return" gets highlighted with  
"function cannot be called with the given argument list"  
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try: `Tb_Return->Text = GetTb;`  (`GetTb` is already a string).